# Network Error 405: Post made from Browser to Localhost WCF REST Web Service

Tags: .net, json, wcf

I am writing a website that makes use of a dotnet rest web service. I have complete control over both projects.

Just today I implemented a post web service. It works when I post with Fiddler. This morning I ran some tests from the Website and all seemed ok. I worked on another issue (getting the post content right with fiddler) and I return to posting from the browser but now the whole website is exhibiting CORS behavior - blank returns, etc. Furthermore, the just implemented post just started returning 405 method not allowed errors

```
"NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed - http://localhost:50122/MyService/ListMarkers"
```

Here is the website code:

```
 function postAjax(){
    var markers = 
    { "listmarkers":
    [{ "position": "128.3657142857143", "markerPosition": "7" },
                   { "position": "235.1944023323615", "markerPosition": "19" },
                   { "position": "42.5978231292517", "markerPosition": "-3" }]
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: window.url + "/PocShimService.svc/ListMarkers",
        // The key needs to match your method's input parameter (case-sensitive).
        data: JSON.stringify(markers),
        //data: markers,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){alert(data);},
        failure: function(errMsg) {
            alert(errMsg);
        }
    });

}
```

Here is the server config having to do with access control:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Any ideas? Suggestions?

Comment: Post you service code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your domain name same for the WCF and client app then you have to try **window.location.origin** instead of **window.url**. Your ajax request should be look like

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: window.location.origin + "/PocShimService.svc/ListMarkers",
    // The key needs to match your method's input parameter (case-sensitive).
    data: JSON.stringify(markers),
    //data: markers,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){alert(data);},
    failure: function(errMsg) {
        alert(errMsg);
    }
});
```

Comment: This did work, I needed to move the website to the same url/port as the web service. I would like to avoid running the website on the same place as my web services. Any advice?

Comment: In that case you have to call WCF on server side because cross browser security concerns